# simple matplotlib problem - variable does not work

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why this is not working?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

f1 = input ('funcao1: ')
f2 = input ('funcao2: ')

x = np.linspace(-3, 3)
plt.plot(x, f1)
plt.plot(x, f2)
plt.show()
```

when I change f1 and f2 to the functions themselves, it works. when I substitute for input variables, no.
ERROR:

```
funcao1: x**2
funcao2: x+2
Traceback (most recent call last)
File "capitao.py", line 8, in <module>
 plt.plot(x, funcao1)
 File "C:\Users\Me\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 2840, in plot    
return gca().plot(
File "C:\Users\Me\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py", line 1743, in plot 
lines = [*self._get_lines(*args, data=data, **kwargs)]
 File "C:\Users\Me\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 273, in __call__
yield from self._plot_args(this, kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Me\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 369, in _plot_args
linestyle, marker, color = _process_plot_format(tup[-1])
File "C:\Users\Me\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 146, in _process_plot_format
raise ValueError(
ValueError: Illegal format string "x**2"; two marker symbols
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use the input() function, the variable f1 is just a string. To evaluate it as a python expression, you have to use the eval() command, as follows:

```
f1 = eval(f1)
```

Hence, your code should look like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(-3, 3)

f1 = input ('funcao1: ')
f2 = input ('funcao2: ')
f1 = eval(f1)
f2 = eval(f2)

plt.plot(x, f1)
plt.plot(x, f2)
plt.show()
```

Comment: its not working. NameError: name 'x' is not defined

Comment: I edited the answer. Indeed, x must have been defined before the eval function.